# Applying Gradient to UIImage Smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to apply gradient to UIImage using CoreGraphic; however, the result I got is not very nice. I want to create a black to transparent gradient at the bottom of the image to create a contrast for me to place some text. However, the gradient I was able doesn't blend well with the image; **you can clearly see the separation in the center**. The result I am looking for is like this application: http://capptivate.co/2014/02/17/yummly-3/
How should I apply the gradient to achieve this? ( I have to apply this to large quantity of images ).

My Result:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
func imageWithGradient(img:UIImage!) -> UIImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size)
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    img.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.50, 1.0]
    //1 = opaque
    //0 = transparent
    let bottom = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
    let top = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor

    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
        [top, bottom], locations)


    let startPoint = CGPointMake(img.size.width/2, 0)
    let endPoint = CGPointMake(img.size.width/2, img.size.height)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: Try setting  Y of startPoint and endPoint out of image bounds so  gradient size will be taller and the difference in colors will be less noticeable. For example set startPoint Y to  `-img.size.height/4` and endPoint  `img.size.height*1.25`. If color at the end of the screen looks too transparent then increase bottom color alpha for a bit aswell

Comment: @zellb I tried it and the line in the middle is still quite visible. Unlike the app in the link I showed, which is very smooth. Do you have any idea what the use to apply the filter? Or is it better to just create a filter in photoshop and apply it on another image.

Answer (score 10):

**SWIFT 3**

```
func imageWithGradient(img:UIImage!) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    img.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let bottom = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    let top = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor

    let colors = [top, bottom] as CFArray

    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colors, locations: locations)

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: img.size.width/2, y: 0)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: img.size.width/2, y: img.size.height)

    context!.drawLinearGradient(gradient!, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: UInt32(0)))

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
}
```

Comment: thanks! Working perfect for me. I just change locations = [0.7, 1.0] to just cover the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out in a Swift playground, I couldn't replicate the exact issue you are describing, however here are some suggestions that you could try.

You could change the way you set up the stops in the gradient, I think it would make more sense to instead of shifting the gradient using the stops, shift the start point, i.e instead of starting from the top edge, start from the vertical center, something like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))

let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
let bottom = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
let top = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor

let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
               [top, bottom], locations)

let startPoint = CGPointMake(image.size.width / 2, image.size.height / 2)
let endPoint = CGPointMake(image.size.width / 2, image.size.height)
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)

let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Notice locations is now 0 and 1, while the `startPoint` y coordinate has shifted downwards.

Alternatively, look at passing `kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation` as an option to `CGContextDrawLinearGradient`, as that could also make a difference.